# JS switch case in every second character in a string

Tags: javascript

The function is supposed to take a string and switch the case of every second character. For example:

```
input: 'HelloWorld'  output: 'HElLowoRlD'
input: 'abcdefg'  output: 'aBcDeFg'
input: 'TONYmontana'  output: 'ToNymOnTaNa'
```

My function doesn't work, why?

```js
function switchCase(text) {
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      if (text[i] === text[i].toLowerCase()) {
        text[i] = text[i].toUpperCase();
      } else {
        text[i] = text[i].toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  }
  return text;
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you can't change them in-place, you can instead create a new empty string and add each character to that

Comment: If strings are immutable, how does this function manage to change the input string?
`function changeStr(str) {
str = str + "X";
return str; 
}`

Comment: Strings are immutable means you can't change string in place like `str[0] = 'a'`, but `str = str + 'X'` is replace the whole `str` variable with new value, so that works.

Comment: I thought by this code `text[i] = text[i].toUpperCase()` I'm replacing the letter with i index with a capital letter, and then it will be remembered as the updated version of the original string (it would overwrite the original string).

Answer (score 3):

You should store the new value in a string and return that from the function:

```js
function secondCase(text) {
  let newValue = ''; // declare a variable
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 !== 0) {
      if (text[i] === text[i].toLowerCase()) {
        newValue += text[i].toUpperCase();  // concatenate the modified letter
      }
      else {
        newValue += text[i].toLowerCase(); // concatenate the modified letter
      }
    }
    else newValue += text[i]; // concatenate the unmodified letter
  }
  return newValue; // return
}

console.log(secondCase('HelloWorld'));
console.log(secondCase('abcdefg'));
console.log(secondCase('TONYmontana'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The string should be written to a new string because strings are [immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Immutable?retiredLocale=nl). Alternative approach: map and join an array representation of the word:

```js
const ucEverySecondChr = word => [...word]
  .map( (c, i) =>
    i && i%2 != 0 ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase() )
  .join('');
  
console.log(ucEverySecondChr("helloworld"));
console.log(ucEverySecondChr("abcdefg"))
console.log(ucEverySecondChr("TONYmontana"));
```

[after comment] Immutability and [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_scope)

```js
let log = (...strs) => document.querySelector(`#result`)
  .insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, strs.join(`\n`) + `\n`);

log(`<h3>About immutability of strings</h3>`);

let str = `lt4`;
str[2] = `X`;
str.toUpperCase();
str.concat(`You won't see me here`);
log(`<code>let str = \`lt4\`;`,
     `<span class="comment">Whatever you do to me, I (str) `+
     `won't budge ...</span>`,
    `str[2] = \`X\`;`,
    `str.toUpperCase();`,
    `str.concat(\`You won't see me here\`);</code>`, 
    `[str] is immutable, so it is not changed. It's value is <b>${str}</b>`);

log(``,`---`, `[str] passed to the function exists ` +
    `only within the called function scope. ` +
    `The original value does not change, so the ` +
    `<i>return value</i> of <code class="inline">changeStr(str);</code> is <b>${
        changeStr(str)}</b>, but the <i>value of [str]</i> is still => <b>${
          str}</b>`);

str = changeStr(str);
log(``,`---`,
    `<code>str = changeStr(str);`, 
    `<span class="comment">Hey, I (str) suddenly feel different</span></code>`,
    `Now you changed the original [str] by (re)assigning the return ` +
    `value of <code class="inline">changeStr(str)</code>. So ` +
    `the value of [str] is now <b>${str}</b>`);

let strObj = new String(`Hello`);
strObj += ` world`;
log(``, `---`, 
    `<code>let strObj = new String(\`Hello\`);`,
    `<span class="comment">I (strObj) am incomplete, change me!</span>`,
    `strObj += \` world\`;</code>`,
    `To be complete: ` +
    `if your string variable is a <i>real instance</i> of `+
    `<code class="inline">String</code> ` +
    `you can change it without (re)assigning, `+
    `so the value of [strObj] is now <b>${strObj}</b>`);

function changeStr(str) {
  if (str.length < 4) {
    str += " =&gt; there we are!";
  }
  
  return str;  
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
  margin: 2em;
}

#result {
  font-familiy: monospace3;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  max-width: 75vw;
}

code {
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  max-width: 70vw;
}

.comment {
  color: #777;
}

.comment:before {
  content: '// ';
}

code.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: If strings are immutable, how does this function manage to change the input string? This function somehow changes (updates) the input string:
`function changeStr(str) {
    
if (str.length < 4) {
       
 str = str + "X";
    }

return str; 
}`

Comment: A string passed to a function only exists within the function scope, it is sort of copied into the function. See the second snippet for a demonstration of that.

Answer (score 0):

Because javascript strings are immutable, so code like `text[i] = 'a'` doesn't work.

You can convert string to array to do what you want, eg:

```
function toggleCase(c) {
  return c === c.toLowerCase() ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase();
}

function secondCase(text) {
  return text.split('').map((c, i) => i % 2 !== 0 ? toggleCase(c) : c).join('');
}
```

Comment: If strings are immutable, how does this function manage to change the input string? This function somehow changes (updates) the input string: `function changeStr(str) {if (str.length < 4) {str = str + "X"; }  return str;}`

Comment: See my comments below your question.

Comment: @NataliaGrzywacz Here the existing string memory is not mutated. New memory for the newly appended string is created for each append operation.

Answer (score 0):

In js strings are immutable. So u may handle your case like below

```
function setCharAt(str, index, chr) {
    return str.substring(0, index) + chr + str.substring(index + 1);
}

function switchCase(text) {
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 !== 0) {
            if (text[i] === text[i].toLowerCase()) {
                text = setCharAt(text, i, text[i].toUpperCase());
            } else {
                text = setCharAt(text, i, text[i].toLowerCase());
            }
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: did you try this one on any large strings?

Comment: No, but I'm pretty sure there wont be any issue

Comment: I'm guessing as a result of all the temporary strings created, that it might be quite slow.